Joint probability mass function and independence

A fair coin is tossed three times. Let X be the number of heads in the first two tosses and Y be the number of tails in the last two tosses.


a) What is the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ and it's marginal functions
b) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?
c) What's the $P(X < Y)$
d) What is the conditional probability function of $P(X = x|Y = y)$ for all values of $x$ and $y$.

I have a table of pmf as follows:
$$
  \begin{array}{l|llll}
      X \backslash Y
    & 0
    & 1
    & 2
    & \sum
    \\
    \hline
      0
    & 0
    & 1/8
    & 1/8
    & 1/4
    \\
      1
    & 1/8
    & 1/4
    & 1/8
    & 1/2
    \\
      2
    & 1/8
    & 1/8
    & 0
    & 1/4
    \\
    \hline
      \sum
    & 1/4
    & 1/2
    & 1/4
  \end{array}
$$
b) I'm not sure here, but I think they are independent because the product of marginal function cannot be zero, if I take the first row and column, values of: $\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \neq 0$.
Is this reasoning correct?
c) There are three cases, first is $x=0, y=1$, second $x=0, y=2$ and third $x=1, y=2$, so it's $\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{8}$
d) I'm not sure how to do this one. Do I just make the "same" table? How do I calculate the values to fill in?

I have a doubt about the table. Why does the event $0$ heads in the first two flips and $0 $ heads in the second two flips have 0 probability?

@rcescon Because there will always be an overlap in the middle. if the throws would be XYZ, then Y must equal to X or Z and thus will count towards either heads or tails. So 0 tails and 0 heads in three tosses is not possible.

Yeah sorry, my bad. I read X,Y being both the number of heads in the first two and last two flips while Y is the number of tails.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this would imply that in your table, $$\Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)] = \Pr[X = x]\Pr[Y = y].$$  In other words, you would be able to take any row and column of the table, and the product of the marginal probabilities in the respective row and column would equal the joint probability in that row and column.  But we can see this is not true; for example, $0 \ne \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4}$.  So $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.
(c) is correct.
For (d), recall that for events $A$ and $B$,
$$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[A \cap B]}{\Pr[B]}.$$
Hence
$$\Pr[X = x \mid Y = y] = \frac{\Pr[(X = x) \cap (Y = y)]}{\Pr[Y = y]}.$$
What this means in terms of the entries in your table is that you simply divide the nine joint probabilities in the table by the respective marginal probability in the same column.  So for example,
$$\Pr[X = 1 \mid Y = 0] = \frac{\Pr[(X = 1) \cap (Y = 0)]}{\Pr[Y = 0]} = \frac{1/8}{1/4} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
